# How can I split or organize big shell scripts into small scripts and call it in main scirpt?

Tags: shell

I am working on a 500 line shell script, any idea to break it in smaller modules or reusable shell script which I could invoke in main.sh file? 
I am looking for code maintainability and reusability ie DRY.

When I tried to call break down main.sh in first.sh and second.sh etc.

where

```
    first.sh
    FOO=fobar
    function hello(){
    echo "hellow
    }
```

```
    main.sh
    echo "calling main script by including sub scripts"
    first.sh
    echo $FOO
    hello
```

I am not able to access my variable and methods when I run ./main.sh
Output
`line 20: hello: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

Given that you already have many functions, consider moving the functions into separate files (usually, '.sh' suffix), therefore creating library that can be sources into your script (or other scripts).

Ideally, the library will only have function definitions, and variable initialization. If needed, and possible, you can create multiple libraries, grouping related functions together.

my-script

```
source myscript-lib.sh

  # Call functions from library
hello
```

myscript-lib.sh

```
function hello {
   echo "Hello"
}
```

Note1: that 'source ...' will use PATH to locate scripts without full path names. From the question reference to `first.sh`, this seems to be consistent with the current code, probably having `.` in the PATH.

Note2: The 'source' can be replaced with '.', but this will (in my experience) create less readable code `. myscript-lib.sh`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its helpful I am about to start my massive refactor of my code based on your guidance/example.